# Is it standard to make each user sign up for a 3rd party API key?

Tags: api, open-source, api-key

I want to make a desktop application which will need to use a 3rd party REST API to get information. However, the number of requests is limited by the API Key. If I use one API key for all users, the request quota will be exhausted really fast. Now, is it standard (and legal) to make each user sign up for his/her own API key? How are API keys used in context of open-source projects?

To generate the API key, I want to make a sign up form within the application, where the user puts in his/her information and the application sends those information to the 3rd party website to get an API key. Does that sound right?

Answer (score 1):

In general the use of an API is limited to the requests from one machine and not to the API key most of the time.

Again depending of the type of third party services you are using, but the requests to the service should be established by the client not the server.

For example if you want to know geographic coordinates from a specific place, but obviously you can't ask the user directly for GPS coordinates. So you implement the Google Maps Javascript Library into your app which requests the Google API for the coordinates to the human readable address and returns it to the client. This in turn sends the data to your server.

In this way your server never comes into contact with the third party service.

If you have sensitive data or data which shouldn't be manipulated by the user you have to request from your server directly of course. But take a look into the documentation of the service before hack something together which isn't in the intention of the service provider.

**Never ever try to outwit a service provider. They will detect your inappropriate use and block you for all time!**